# Django: UnicodeDecodeError while trying to read template 500.html

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-web-services, django-templates

I am trying to deploy my django application to a production environment with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In my staging environment, where I have `DEBUG=True`, everything is fine, but when `DEBUG=False` I am getting the error `UnicodeDecodeError while trying to read template /home/docker/code/django-app/templates/500.html`

Here is my `500.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% load i18n %}

{% block title_html %}{% trans 'Server error (500)' %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
    <h1>{% trans 'Server Error <em>(500)</em>' %}</h1> 
    <p>
        {% trans "There has been an error. It's been reported to the site administrators and should be fixed shortly. Thank you for your patience." %}
    </p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: could you post the whole traceback?

Comment: That one line is the only error I am seeing in the logs reported back to me from Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: it might be that your 500 template is not saved in utf8. do you use eclipse?

Comment: No. I am using Komodo Edit 8 text editor. My `base.html` file that `500.html` inherits from also contains the tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">`... if that would affect anything.

Comment: can you check in komodo what encoding it has: ``"Load the file, right-click on the tab, choose properties & settings, Click on File Preferences, Under File Settings/Encodings"``

Save the file.

Comment: It was previously Western European (Mac-Roman). Just changed it to UTF-8 and pushed to DockerHub. It runs on the local django server just fine with `DEBUG=False` We'll see if that fixes the problem on EB when the image finishes building.

Comment: nice. let me know if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your 500 template is not saved in UTF-8 encoding. Since you are using Komodo Edit, try to change its encoding to utf8 in:

> Load the file -> right-click on the tab -> properties & settings -> File Preferences -> File Settings/Encodings

Comment: I agree, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/unicode/

"If you pass a string to Django that has been encoded in some other format, things will go wrong in interesting ways. Usually, Django will raise a UnicodeDecodeError at some point."

Comment: No longer seeing the error in the EB logs. Thank you. Unfortunately HealthCheck is still coming up Red, and for the life of me I can't figure out why...

Comment: (Unrelated to this exact question but...) A simple check to my uWSGI error log in the docker container found why the HealthCheck came up RED. The HealthCheck IP address was not part of my `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, so was getting a `400 BAD REQUEST` error. I added this IP address to my `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Hopefully this IP address doesn't change frequently... otherwise I'll need a better solution.